# mongodb wildcard match all values for specific key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I am trying to figure out how to match a key and return all the values for that key. Is it possible to give the value as a wildcard? I want to return everything for that specific key using wildcard on the value.

```
db.collection.find({"key" :"*"})
```

Also I was hoping this would return the entire collection as well that had the key with the wildcard value match as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this:

```
db.collection.find({"key": {$exists: true}})
```

This will return all documents in the collection where the key "key" is present.  The entire document is returned.

Comment: This is really delayed due to me getting involved in other projects. But this is what i needed.

Comment: {'$exists': True} worked for me. Thank you great qa

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
db.collection.distinct("key")
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have been more clear in my initially posting for this question. I was hoping to return the entire collection not just the collection with this value.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. To get all documents in a collection, do `db.collection.find()`. Is that what you want?