# How do I query for the value of a key in an object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

all the documentation on this subject seems aimed at retrieving elements from an array stored in mongodb.  I have a document:

```
{
   "user1": { ... },
   "user2": { ... },
   ...
}
```

and want to retrieve the object stored for *user1* but cannot find a way to formulate the query:

```js
collection.find({user1})
```

won't work because it's destructuring of a variable that doesn't exist

```js
var q = {}; q.user1 = '';
collection.find(q)
```

also wouldn't work because it would be looking for '' as the value.

**how is this done??**

and no, please don't post that I need to restructure my data as an array or in some other way.  if it can't be done, just say so.  thanks!

Comment: Is this document a sub document or is it the top level?

Comment: db.collectionName.find( { field: 'value' } ) You have to specify a field name present in the objects user1, user2 etc

Comment: You can use projection `db.coll.find({},{user1:1})`?

Comment: @KiranMathewMohan but there is no field name.  my field name is the value.  it's a key in an object

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar that should not matter because at any point I might want to retrieve something using this mechanism at any level of nesting.  what I'm after is the mechanism

Comment: @ekkis Then try this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44616276/mongodb-wildcard-match-all-values-for-specific-key

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar thank you! that's it.  I've accepted the "duplicate" status for this post